# Nginx loadbalancing in same ip but different ports

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, tomcat

Nginx(80) and two tomcat(8080,18080) were installed on one server.
And i try to loadbalancing

is it possible?

I can proxy pass 80 to 8080, 
but can't to 18080.

Why is this ??T.T

```
http{

upstream backend{
 server localhost:18080;
server localhost:8080
}

server{
listen 80;

location ~ / {
 proxy_pass http://backend;
}
}
```

Comment: it is possible to load balancing on same ip, please check whether port 18080 is accessible from local or not.

Comment: It seems to possible ,  I can access to 18080 port with web browser , ex> http://ipaddress:18080 it works well

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Comment: I coded as above , but nginx proxy_pass feature works on 8080 port only , not works on 80 to 18080 i tested proxy_pass only using the 'server localhost:18080' but its not worked , and i tested proxy_pass only using the source that 'server localhost:8080 it worked well

Comment: You know that the bit you posted above has a syntax error in it. You should test your configuration before attempting to reload nginx, because it will refuse to load a configuration with errors and will continue with its previous configuration.

Comment: Thanks but it has not error of syntax on server ..

Comment: How have you actually determined that load balancing does not work? Please post the exact same configuration here as you have in the server so that we don't waste our time fixing errors that are not there.

Comment: Startup two tomcat and shutdown one tomcat on 8080 port , but it(load balancing to 18080) didn't work i wanna post configuration but i can't because i remove that .. my fault ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this

It faults by SELinux..

Comment: Please add more details to your answer. How was it an SELinux error and what did you do to fix it?